# How to create Image of your system which has lot of software installed

Tags: windows, images

I want to create an image of a already setup windows7 machine which has lots of software installed like VS,Sql server and even IIS has lots of websites and lots more. I have another new machine and i just want to install all the software with the system image i have created.

I am not sure if it is feasible or how it is done? But it will surely save lot of time for new hires in my company to avoid lengthy installation steps and becoming productive asap.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A clean install has its advantages. One of those is a check if your installation documentation is up to date **before** you need the new machine. (e.g. is your disaster recovery document clear and correct).

Answer (score 1):

To create a back up follow these steps:

1. Open the Control Panel
2. Click on the Backup and Restore icon.
3. Click on the Create a system image link.
4. Select the location to where you would like to save the backup image at, and click on the Next button.
5. If available, check any additional hard drives or partitions that you would like to include in the backup image with the Windows 7 (System and C: ) partition or hard drive, and click on the Next button.
6. Click on the Start backup button.
7. When it is finished you will see this create a System Repair disc pop-up window. Click on No. (See screenshot below)
8. Click on the Close button.

This will include IIS settings since they are saved :  \windows\system32\inetsrv\config directory (which is under the C drive)

Your title asks for an image of the system but the question asks more about the software. Are you actually after just an image of the installed software so you can just dump it onto a new machine as I don't think this will work due to licensing issues etc.

Comment: first, thanks for your answer. and yes, i want to dump it into another machine right away. Licensing should not be an issue as i think we use our internal software only but i need to confirm this.